# Geodesics on a sphere without using spherical coordinates.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, geodesic

I've just came up with this coordinate system (don't know if it exists or it has been previously invented):
$$
\mathbf r = (r\cos{\theta}\cos{\varphi}, \; r\sin{\varphi},  \; r\sin{\theta}\cos{\varphi})
$$
This are the coordines of a vector confined to a plane with a normal that is allowed to rotate around the $y$ axes. Then the rest of the coordinates variables are found by creating a "local" system polar coordinates in that plane.

[image: #1]

[image: #2]

Now, all orbital-like motion would simply be described by $\varphi$. For example an orbit of radius $1$, with $\theta = \pi/2$, would be written as:
$$
\varphi(t) = \omega t + \varphi_0 \\
\mathbf r = (0, \sin(\omega t + \varphi_0), \cos(\omega t + \varphi_0))
$$

This could be useful for describing circular-ish trajectories. For example, geodesics on a sphere. Is easily to see that:
$$
s = \int_\gamma \sqrt{ dr^2 + r^2 d\varphi^2 + r^2 \cos^2 (\varphi) d \theta^2 }
$$
By appliying the Euler-Lagrange equations I get the following (note that $r'(t) = 0$):
$$
\varphi''(t) = -\cos(\varphi(t)) \sin(\varphi(t)) \theta'(t)^2
$$
But I was expecting something like:
$$
\varphi''(t) = 0
$$

My question is: Is it possible to get the equation I described before, using Euler-Lagrange Equations. Is a solution like: $\varphi(t) = \omega t + \varphi_0$, to be expected from this?

Comment: Aren't these just [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) with entries and angles mixed up? Like taking $\frac\pi2-\alpha$ instead of $\alpha$ somewhere and then permuting the entries.

Comment: Probably. The important thing is that any kind of motion that is related with a great circle on the sphere is exclusively described by $\varphi$. Thats the way i've defined them.

Comment: I highly doubt that this is true for the pair (this stuff, $\varphi$) any more than it is true of the pair (spherical coodinates, $\theta$), but since it's a finitary statement that I won't be checking, might as well leave it at that.

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself wrong. I mean, $\varphi$ expreses the angle covered in that great circle. But you, obviusly need a plane to define that motion (as well as a radius). What I meant before, is that once setted the plane angle, this great circle is fully described by $\varphi$.

Comment: These **are** just spherical coordinates putting the poles on the $y$-axis and using latitude instead of co-latitude for one coordinate. You can indeed traverse any great circle through the $y$-axis just by varying $\varphi$ from $0$ to $2\pi.$ But you cannot use $\varphi$ alone to traverse any great circle that does not intersect the $y$-axis. Standard spherical coordinates similarly can trace a great circle through the $z$-axis just by varying the co-latitude, but they need to vary both coordinates for any other great circle.